# How to add Center focused image with most of top and bottom part hidden within card view?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-cardview

I am making an android application, giving an `listView` having card views within it. I want to customize card view with one image and some details(one title). I want just some part of the image (mostly center part) to show within it(card view) and most of the top and bottom part of image should get hidden so that when user will click on the image then it will display whole image with detailed description in next activity. So basically all I want is some code so that card view automatically takes just some part of image as I mentioned above and show it to user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand you right :-)

In your ImageView in XML add this

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Run it and tell me if this is the effect you wanted?

Comment: Well if we both mean the same effect than yes it is :-)